# How is "vinum rubrum" right?

Tags: classical-latin, linguistics

Sorry, I am a beginner so I don't really know much. But doesn't the genetive singular of the word red should be rubri?

Comment: You might want to step back a second. 1. Where did you see the phrase? 2. What do you think it even means? 3. What are you trying to figure out? Do you want to know about genitives, about what *vinum rubrum* means, or something else?

Comment: In the phrase Velisne vinum rubrum. I am not sure if it's correct

Answer (score 3):

*Rubrum* is an adjective that agrees with *vinum*. The context of your phrase makes it clear they're both in the accusative (formally they could also be in the nominative or vocative), because *vinum rubrum* is the direct object of the sentence; "Velisne vinum rubrum?" translates to "Do you want red wine?".

There are languages that would use a partitive genitive construction there (e.g. French "Tu veux *du* vin rouge?"), but Latin does not.

Comment: A partitive genitive can be used in Latin too (although I'm not sure if it'd make any sense here), but then *du vin rouge = vini rubri* with both words in the genitive case.